# How to change IRQ priorities on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, priority, irq

I'm trying to figure out how to change the IRQ priorities for devices on Ubuntu (the specific release I have is 11.10).  I found [this question and answer](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1860619) which says it can be done, but it appears to only work for older distros of Ubuntu. I also looked into [irqtune](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man8/irqtune.8.html), but it says "command not found" when I try it in the terminal.

Is it possible to change the IRQ priorities in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Generally it is a good idea to let Ubuntu manage IRQ's, however there are tools out there which can manage them for you if you have some hardware problems, such as "irqbalance".
check the link and see if it helps you solve your problem.

[IRQbalance](https://irqbalance.org/index.html)