# New custom-built computer total freeze (unresponsive keys and mouse) - Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: freeze, crash, nvidia-geforce, amd-ryzen, ubuntu-22.04

I very recently bought a new personal computer that was custom-built with new out-of-the-box components, pre-installed with deactivated Windows. I decided to install Ubuntu 22.04, which works totally fine on my work's >8-year old computer. The problem is that ever since I got my computer, it freezes randomly, a few times every hour. Keyboard and mouse are unresponsive, the screen freezes and sounds stop playing.

There are some specific scenarios that cause this freezing (randomly, do not happen 100% of the time) and that is after idleness, watching Youtube videos on a browser (Firefox or Chrome), making posts about my problem or generally using a browser. I haven't noticed freezing under other occasions, though I may have missed something. I had a 2-hour zoom meeting by Chrome today (no youtube or other tabs open), with a few terminals and Visual Studio Code running and my computer did not freeze.

To fix this, I tried installing NVIDIA drivers (nvidia-driver-515 and nvidia-driver-470), I tried changing some settings in BIOS, but nothing worked. I've already posted my problem here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1418305/ubuntu-22-04-system-freeze-randomly-completely-unresponsive-keys-mouse

Specs:

Model: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. X570 GAMING X
 RAM: 16GB
 CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 5700g with Radeon graphics × 16
 GPU: GeForce RTX 3060 Ti
 Disk 1 - SSD (1TB): Reserved BIOS (1 MB), EFI (1 GB), swap (64 GB), "\" (~400 GB), "\home" (the rest)
 Disk 2 - HDD (4TB): "\hdd" (all memory)
 PSU: CX650M, 80 plus Bronze

I'm also sharing the latest `journalctl -b` outputs with this link: https://file.io/sfqDy7nM1kmX

**EDIT**:
Stress-tested the GPU with glmark2: score 757
Stress-tested the RAMs-CPU with `stress --cpu 16 --io 16 --vm 4 --vm-bytes 1024M --timeout 30s`, no problem.

Comment: It could be IRQ (interrupt request) issues, more likely on a custom-built machine. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DebuggingIRQProblems, https://superuser.com/questions/517087/how-to-change-irq-priorities-on-ubuntu

Comment: I understand the basis for IRQ and I'm checking it right now, but is this possible in a new machine?

Comment: I answered a similar problem here, it might help: https://askubuntu.com/a/1442478/118029